# using e.g. ssh over openvpn, is the traffic actually addressed to 22?

Tags: openvpn, port, tunneling

Given that Client A and Client B are using OpenVPN and they are on the same virtual network.
A connects to B via e.g. SSH.
In front of B there is an external Firewall or whatever.

Is the traffic which is monitored by the firewall actually addressed to port 22 then?
So is it port 22 B should enable or is it more like the VPN port?

To take it short: am I right that all traffic from and to the VPN is "tunneled" via a single Port and therefore only this single ports needs to be open?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing to me.

VPN is VPN and Services running on a specific port is a service running on a specific port.

Now, if you target services are fronted by another firewall after the VPN endpoint, you also need to play with that firewall to allow traffic to the destination endpoint you want to get to.